# Woocommerce - Get product category 2nd level category

Tags: categories, plugins

I have 3 levels deep product categories like following :

A
|--B
|---C

I want to get B, but don't know how to do.
I can get all product categories, but don't know how to filter out.

Here the code I use to get product categories :
            ID, 'product_cat' );

```
            foreach( $product_category as $cat ):
            if( 0 == $cat->parent )
                echo $cat->name;
            endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the parent category ID, you can use get_terms() function.

```
$args = array(
     'parent' => 100 // id of the direct parent
);

$cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
  echo $cat->name;
}
```

Here is more information on this function and additional arguments you can use.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms